How to prove that any tracefree symmetric tensor can be written as tracefree part of symmetrized tensor product of vectors?
A tensor cannot always be decomposed as tensor product of two vectors. For example, see this post.
However in "Differential representation of multipole fields" by Castillo and Mendez-Garrido to which I got referred from the famous Electromagnetism textbook by Zangwill, it is said that a tracefree symmetric tensor $T^{\alpha_1 \alpha_2 ... \alpha_l}$ can be written as a tracefree part of symmetrized tensor product of $l$ vectors, where $l$ is the rank of the tensor i.e.
$$T^{\alpha_1 \alpha_2 ... \alpha_l}=v_1^{(\alpha_1}v_2^{\alpha_2}... v_l^{\alpha_l)}-\text{traces}$$
where $()$ is used to denote symmetrization. How to prove this statement i.e. how to prove that such a decomposition exists? Note that I am not looking for a particular form of the traces, but to prove that such a decomposition can be done for these class of tensors. The paper refers to a book which uses 3-spinor techniques to prove this result, but I believe a more elementary proof is possible and well known in math literature. Hence I am looking for an alternative proof of the above fact.
At the risk of asking two questions in one, I would also like to know what is the necessary and sufficient condition on the type of a tensor to admit such a decomposition in terms of tensor products of vectors? For example, is the condition "tracefree" really required? Can this be generalised to other more arbitrary tesnors.
